# Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, angular8

ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.ts:21:46 - error TS2339: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.

> 21       localStorage.setItem("xAuthToken", res.token);

**login.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  sendCredential(username:string,password:string){
    let url="http://localhost:8181/token";
    let encodedCredentials= btoa(username+":"+password);
    let basicHeader="Basic: "+encodedCredentials;
    let header=new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization' : basicHeader
    });
    return this.http.get(url,{headers:header});
  }
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
onSubmit(){
    this.loginService.sendCredential(this.credential.username, this.credential.password).subscribe(
      res => {
          console.log(res);
      localStorage.setItem("xAuthToken", res.token);
          this.loggedIn = true;
          location.reload();
      },
      error => {
          console.log(error);
      }
  );
  }
```

Comment: what you get while console logging res?

Comment: originally "localStorage.setItem (" xAuthToken ", res.json (). token);" It should be this way, but no need to write json anymore and I didn't write json either. But I still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

change 'res' to (res:any)

```js
onSubmit(){
    this.loginService.sendCredential(this.credential.username, this.credential.password).subscribe(
      (res:any) => {
          console.log(res);
      localStorage.setItem("xAuthToken", res.token);
          this.loggedIn = true;
          location.reload();
      },
      error => {
          console.log(error);
      }
  );
  }
```